# Syntax while setting schema for Pyspark.sql using StructType

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am new to spark and was playing around with Pyspark.sql. According to the pyspark.sql documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#), one can go about setting the Spark dataframe and schema like this:

```
spark= SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType, IntegerType, 
StructType, StructField

rdd = sc.textFile('./some csv_to_play_around.csv'

schema = StructType([StructField('Name', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('DateTime', TimestampType(), True)
                     StructField('Age', IntegerType(), True)])

# create dataframe
df3 = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd, schema)
```

My question is, what does the `True` stand for in the `schema` list above? I can't seem to find it in the documentation. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It means if the column allows null values, `true` for nullable, and `false` for not nullable

> StructField(name, dataType, nullable): Represents a field in a StructType. The name of a field is indicated by name. The data type of a field is indicated by dataType. nullable is used to indicate if values of this fields can have null values.

Refer to [Spark SQL and DataFrame Guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) for more informations.

Comment: Be aware that this "feature" is known not be reliable and not working. Test it before using and if I were you I would not rely on it

Comment: may be this is old post by thank you so much @yhshen for resolution. I literally killed my 5-6 hours finding the issue.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use a datatype string:

```
schema = 'Name STRING, DateTime TIMESTAMP, Age INTEGER'
```

There's not much documentation on datatype strings, but they mention them in the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=registerjava#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.createDataFrame). They're much more compact and readable than StructTypes